# Bagweaver Artificer Subclass

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, artificer, archetype

This is my first ever Subclass that I've made. I am looking for any constructive feedback. Any advice an things to remove, things that are too strong or too weak or too much. Any feedback is welcome.

Bagweaver Subclass

The bag of holding has stood out to you as an extraordinary marvel of ingenuity. You seek to master the art of using these miraculous bags extradimensional properties. No matter what the task at hand is you will always be prepared, and your party can count on you to have just the thing they need.

BAGWEAVER SPELLS

Starting at 3rd level, you always have certain spells prepared after you reach particular levels in this class, as shown in the Bagweaver Spells table. These spells count as artificer spells for you, but they don't count against the number of artificer spells you prepare

BAGWEAVER SPELLS

3rd Identify, Tensers Floating Disk

5th Arcane Lock, Rope Trick

9th Glyph of Warding, Tiny Servant

13th Leomund's Secret Chest, Fabricate

17th Planar Binding, Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion

BAG OF RESTING

You have studied the inner workings of a bag of holding and have managed to create a space within to call your own. At level 3 you and up to 5 allies can take refuge within a bag of holding mimicking the effects of a tiny hut spell while inside. You can now spend up to 8 hours within a bag of holding. During a long rest in the bag, you can dedicate 4 hours to working on crafting. This refuge is not included in the carry capacity of a bag.

BAG OF SAFEKEEPING

Your refuge within a bag of holding has allowed you to ensure the safety of your items. When a bag of holding is torn, any objects within are kept within the confines of the refuge, and any creatures are safely placed within 10 feet of the torn bag. The next time you create a bag of holding, you regain access to the items within. Moreover, you gain the knowledge to nest one bag within another without complications.

INTERDIMENSIONAL NETWORK

Your mastery over bags of holding allows you to actually attune to the bags. At level 5 you gain 2 additional attunement slots. These slots can only be used for bags of holding. While within 80 feet of each other, bags of holding attuned to you form a connected network of space, sharing their dimensional space, and adding together their storage capacities. As a bonus action you can leap between 2 connected bags of holding. This can be used a number of times equal to your PB per short or long rest.

PORTA-SATCHEL

Also at 5th level you bags of holding gain the ability to teleport. As a bonus action, you can choose one bag of holding connected to the network and move it to an

unoccupied space within 60 feet that you can see.

DIMENSIONAL WINDOW

At 9th level your mastery of the extradimensional space allows you to quickly reach into it without the need for a bag. As an action you can move an object you can touch into or out of your network storage without the need for a bag. this can be used a number of times equal to your intelligence modifier, and you regain uses after a long rest.

BAG OF AID

Also at 9th level you are more able to aid allies that hold your bags. When you or an an ally is holding your bag on their person, they gain the following benefits:

You can draw ammo or weapons from the bag as part of the action to use them

You can use a bonus action to allow any attacks this turn to be used as if they were from a different connected bags space. Does not provide disadvantage to ranged weapons if shot from a bag adjacent to a target

DIMENSIONAL FORGE

At 15th level the refuge within your bag of holding has become a haven to you and your allies. The area can now be customized to fit you and your parties needs. It can be altered to provide comfort, and functionality. This haven has become a beacon fo your crafting prowess. While within the area the time and gold required to make magical items is reduced by 25%.

BAGWEAVER INFUSIONS

SADDLEBAG OF HOLDING

This unique bag of holding is made to act like a saddle. The bag will form to fit onto any rideable creature it is placed on, and weighs 20 pounds. The sides of the saddle have pouches that can be used as a bag of holding

DIMENSIONAL WHIP

This whip is made from the leather of a bag of holding and is able to shape itself at will. When attacking on your turn, you can extend the whip up to an additional 10 feet. This whip can also be used to mimic the effects of a rope of climbing. This does not count as a bag of holding for any bagweaver abilities.

ADDITIONAL BAGWEAVER EFFECTS

You are proficient with this whip. A bagweaver can use intelligence when attacking with this whip, and gains extra attack at level 5 with this whip. (Does not stack with any other form of extra attack).

ASTRAL SLING

This sling is connected to the bag of holding and can draw ammunition from the bag as part of the attack action. You no longer need a free hand to load the sling. Also when you make a ranged attack with this sling and hit a target, you can cause the ammunition to ricochet toward a second target within 10 feet of the first, and then make a ranged attack against the second target.

ADDITIONAL BAGWEAVER EFFECTS

As a master of the pocket dimension, a bagweaver can use intelligence when attacking with this sling, and gains extra attack at level 5 with this sling. (Does not stack with any other form of extra attack)

REQUIRES 5TH LEVEL

UNFURLED BAG OF HOLDING

A bag of holding made this way can be used like a cloak. While wearing this cloak you have advantage on stealth checks as your form is obscured with remnants from the dimension within. You can also transport objects from the cloak as if you were using a bag of holding.

DIMENSIONAL ARMOR

This armor is a +1 version of leather armor. While wearing this armor, you can use your reaction to reduce the damage of an attack that hits you by 1d10. This can be used a number of times equal to your PB per short or long rest

REQUIRES 10TH LEVEL

GLOVES OF HOLDING

These special gloves are formatted to allow quick access to the bag of holding's storage. While wearing these gloves, you can acquire or stow items out of or into your bag of holding as a bonus action instead of an action.

REQUIRES 14TH LEVEL

BAG OF SPELLS

This bag of holding cannot connect to your interdimensional network. While holding this bag in your hands you can cast counterspell once. If it succeeds it can store the spell inside it, as long as that spell is no higher than 5th level. You can cast that spell at a later time without expending a spell slot, or any materials. The magic can only stay in the bag until a long rest.

[image: The bagweaver subclass]

[image: Bagweaver Infusions]

Comment: @Hollow I think you should include the actual subclass text in plaintext. The tendered version may be beautiful, but is neither searchable, and likely not accessible to readers with disabilities. Its also to small to read on mobile without zoom/pan.

Comment: There we go. Hope that helps. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Reading Bag of Spells, it seems like this feature/item can only be used to cast counterspell once. Is the intent that you can cast counterspell once each day?

Comment: @Tollef yeah it was meant so that you would have to create the item using the infuse item artificer ability in order to make a other one after a long rest

Comment: I'm writing an answer, but I have no idea how Bag of Resting is supposed to work given that it mentions Tiny Hut. Do you all jump into the Bag, and a shell of force appears around your bag? Do you all jump into the Bag, and a shell of force appears inside the bag so nobody else can jump in? Do you expand your bag into a shell of warped space around your party that mimics a Tiny Hut spell? I'd like to suggest a rewritten version of the feature, but I can't do that if I'm not sure what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial thoughts

I love the ideas in this subclass. Some of the features look a little odd, and they don't seem to work quite how I'd expect a bag expert's abilities to work. The infusions look awesome as well, though they might be a bit too powerful.

### Spell list

This is a utility spell list, which is unusual. Looking at the other Artificer subclasses, they have straightforward combat spells that you want to use every day - exactly what you expect for spells that must always be prepared. For instance, Identify will be a bit of a waste 80% of the time, and an artificer can always prepare it if necessary.

Moreover, all the artificer subclass bonus spells are off-list - they can't be prepared by a normal artificer. In contrast, all but three of your spells are already available to artificers. They fit well, but they're not new. I would suggest changing the list to:

- Unseen Servant, Leomund's Floating Disk
- Misty Step, Locate Object or Cloud of Daggers
- Clairvoyance, Conjure Barrage
- Banishment, Dimension Door or Private Sanctum
- Planar Binding, Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion

This spell list is still highly utility-focused, but now has a few in-combat options. It does not fit as well thematically, but it provides new options to Bagweavers that no other artificer has, similar to the other subclasses.

However, it is mostly made of powerful multipurpose spells, while other subclasses usually get no more than one good spell each spell level; if you want it to fit more and be more balanced, you should either decide to give this subclass on-list spells like Catapult and Levitate, or invent some Bagweaver combat spells.

### 3rd level features

I do not know what Bag of Resting does. I cannot analyze it because it doesn't seem to work in several ways. I might edit in a suggestion/analysis if told what it does.

Regardless, it is pretty odd. Three of the artificer subclasses give straightforward combat options at level 3, very important given that artificers don't have as many spells as wizards - who get convenient utility features. The last one gives a wacky out-of-combat buff ability, and is probably the one to compare.

Bag of Safekeeping is solid; it negates the pain of working with Bags. On the other hand, I'm not sure what happens if you find a non-infusion Bag of Holding while adventuring, and you should clarify that. Do "wild" bags of holding magically rupture safely around you when torn? Do you modify them over a long rest? Can you bring a "wild" bag of holding into one of your bags of holding safely, or vice versa? And of course, what about "tame" bags of holding, which you craft yourself but don't infuse? Your feature needs to clarify all these, maybe just by saying "When a bag of holding *you created* is torn" and "...gain the knowledge to nest one bag you created within another you created without complications."

### 5th level features

Ohhhhh dear. Okay, connected. This is where it starts to become a real mess. You might want to describe the physical shape of the space, for one, since as a bagweaver you are obviously going to have combats that occur partly inside a bag. Presumably each bagspace (roughly a 5-foot cube) adjoins to every other bagspace, each of which has an opening at the top. When you move one bag within 80 feet of another, I assume the spaces suddenly and instantly become magically connected.

What about astral slings? Do they have a doorway, so people can climb out of your sling? Worst of all.... what happens when you nest bags of holding? I think the best solution for nesting is to declare that the bags aren't connected anymore, since they're on separate planes, and the alternative is too horrible to contemplate.

The attunement part is fine; 2 attunement slots seems about right. You might have 3 things that count as bags of holding at a time around level 10, so this fits. You should perhaps specify "You can attune to bags of holding; this provides only the benefits listed below." As is, no bag of holding can be attuned.

The bonus action bag-jump is interesting, but I can't tell if it's good or useless. Can't you already... spend 10 feet of movement to climb into the bag, 5 feet to move into the other adjacent bagspace, and 10 feet of movement to climb out of the other bag? Is this for "bags" that have no entrance, like Dimensional Armor?

Porta-Satchel is fascinating! We have our first real combat ability, and it's a neat one. You can go anywhere, in or out of combat! You can get through a door! You can stick your head out of a satchel and teleport it, becoming the Gnome who Never Leaves His Bag! But it's an intensely, ridiculously versatile tool; if you want to put a per-rest limit on an ability, put it on Porta-Satchel and make Interdimensional Network at-will. Interdimensional Network is just action economy, and not the most useful action economy anyway. Porta-Satchel at-will makes your group's optimal travel strategy a teleporting bag.

### 9th level features

Neat! Dimensional Window is a fun power, 3-4 times a day teleporting objects around. It seems to have an infinite "range," summoning things from your bags a thousand miles away - which is odd, since your bags aren't in a *network* if they're a thousand miles away, they're all separate. I think it would see a lot of use summoning big bricks or teleporting pesky doors into your stash. I also note that it can summon a nested bag of holding containing your party, but that leaves one bag behind. Or it can send your party (and you, and the bag!) from a bag you all jump into. Be careful here; I don't know how to analyze this feature but I love it. Good call not making it at-will.

Bag of Aid is a useful utility power, fitting with a lot of other 9th level artificer abilities. I foresee a familiar carrying a bag 200 feet into the air so your archer can snipe the frost giants, but that's not a problem... and you could already sort of do it with a normal Bag. I would make it not cost a bonus action, because forcing your allies to spend bonus actions is annoying (especially if you have a rogue), but it's your call.

I do question one thing: since an Astral Sling or Dimensional Whip counts as a Bag of Holding, can I whip people by lashing the whip through itself and out another Bag? Do I shoot sling bullets into my own sling? That sounds kind of insane, and I don't want to visualize it.

### 15th(?) level feature

Dimensional Forge's fluff sounds neat (my bag contains a bed now!), but I'm unclear on what you're actually doing. I mean, you could already put a bed in the bag... does your bag air-condition and serve food now? Does it teleport wrenches into your hands? I don't like it because it seems to say you couldn't customize it before. Also, every other artificer subclass gains a serious boost to its previous combat features at 15th level (except Alchemist, which gets a powerful but unrelated set of abilities). In comparison, Bagweaver gets a cost reduction, which is pretty strange and of course depends on how much the DM likes crafting magic items.

### Infusions

Whoa, some of these are surprise class features. I'd be very careful here. One by one:

---

Saddlebag of Holding: This is fun and useful, though I'm not sure what it means that "pouches can be used as a bag of holding." Are there seven tiny pockets, and each gives access to the same Bag? That sounds a little uncomfortable, especially if you're trying to fit into the bag. The specific wording about the bag fitting tells me I can make a Saddlebag for a cat, have the druid turn into a cat, stick the party in the bag, and have the druid carry the party in a saddlebag with his 22.5lb carrying capacity, but that's a niche case.

---

Dimensional Whip: Yep, this is a hidden class feature. Compare this to the Armorer Artificer at level 5. With Thunder Gauntlets, the Armorer does 1d8+int twice, and uses a bonus action to hit for 1d8 more, at the same attack bonus as you, while practically forcing the target to fight you; you attack twice for 1d4+int at a range of 20 feet (using your bonus action on one of your 5th level features). So, not nearly as powerful, but a decent combat option. Yes, this costs you an infusion slot, but you made it give an "extra" magic item by making it also a Rope of Climbing (and it can be used as a Bag for some things).

I'm not sure how a Rope of Climbing fits thematically, as it makes the whip into a 60-foot voice-activated snake; I would remove that, while leaving the other abilities. That makes it decent, but not overpowered.

---

Astral Sling: Hidden class features, part 2! This one is also nice. You get 2 attacks at level 5, and a roughly 50% chance to attack again each time (I assume it can't rebound infinitely!). That's 3 attacks for 1d4+Int, equal to the Armorer's 2d6+int and 1d6+int at a range. Looks fine if you want a combat option, again.

---

Unfurled Bag of Holding: Huh, interesting. I like the idea; it's a variant on a Cloak of Elvenkind, but I'm not sure how the bag of holding part works. Are the items just hidden in your cloak? Can you jump into your cloak with Interdimensional Network? Clearly it's meant to work with Dimensional Window. Can you fold it back up to use it as a bag? I'm not sure how you want all these abilities to combine, so I can't help with how it should be worded.

---

Dimensional Armor: Looks fun. +1 leather armor that gives roughly 3d10 health per short rest might be a bit much; I'd change it to only refresh on long rest, but it's up to you. But it should specify that it uses the Artificer's proficiency bonus, or else it leads to confusing questions about what happens when the PB 2 Fighter uses it twice, then gives it to the PB 3 Barbarian.

---

Gloves of Holding: Um.... so, because of the wording at the start, this thing counts *as* a bag of holding, but it also gives a minor bag-of-holding-use power? It's not very useful if it doesn't have its own space, so I'd recommend noting that it has pouches on the palms or something, assuming that's your idea. I personally think it would be funny if you could make an attack roll as a reaction to try and "block" an arrow with your open pouch-glove (making this a quite good anti-archer item), but I have strange ideas.

---

Bag of Spells: Heh, I like this. Maybe modify the wording to make it clear that:

1. Any creature can use it.
2. It can only be used once total, even if other creatures pick it up.
3. Any creature can cast the stored spell.

Other than that it looks fine, if perhaps a little weak. Less weak if you give it to a Tiny Servant or friendly NPC to use, I guess. Can you jump inside? If you can't, it should say so, or else it's fairly confusing.

### Final thoughts

I love this subclass even more after an in-depth look. I would *love* to play this; I'm dreaming now of trying to convince my DM to let me, whenever I'm next not DMing. But it'd probably be a bit confusing in play.

> You: "I use Dimensional Window to put the big rock slab over the
> portal to Acheron, teleport Tim's Unfurled Bag of Holding to the Magic
> Circle Against Evil, and use my movement to climb down the ladder of
> Lump's Elephant-Sized Saddlebag of Holding and up the ladder that
> leads out Tim's Unfurled Bag of Holding into safety."
>
> Allison: "Hey! You needed to leave the Unfurled Bag of Holding on Tim,
> I was going to attack using Bag of Aid to attack with my Dimensional
> Whip passing through my Dimensional Whip and out of Tim's cloak to hit
> the Balor 20 feet away from him! Now I can't do anything with my turn but
> plink away with my longbow!"

---

I'm not actually sure about the name "Bagweaver". I mean, the Whip even calls out that it's made of leather. Maybe you weave leather strips together? But it's probably fine as a name.

---

I'm very unsure about Planar Binding and Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion as 5th level spells - and not just because one is normally 7th level. Binding takes 1,000 gp, which is definitely not normal for a subclass spell you have prepared every day. Mansion is almost the opposite of what you want: instead of making your bag more of a home, it gives you a backup home. I might switch them out for... Conjure Volley? Passwall? Scrying? Teleportation Circle? Wall of Force? I do not know. My suggested Misty Step also doesn't fit very well, but your options are more limited there.

---

A lot of the fiddly bits become less of a problem if you're the DM, this is only used in your game, and you have a half-hour talk with the player using it. Some of my nitpicks about wording can be easily avoided just by discussing it when your player reaches level 3, if that's the situation.

---

Try to stick with the theme of "Bag" names? Name the features Bag of Resting, Bag of Safekeeping, Bag of Connection, Bag of Blinking, Bag of Storage, Bag of Aid, Bag of Comfort? That's not important, but I think it would be funny.

Comment: Whoof, this was fun but difficult to write. So many overlapping ideas....

Comment: But a dozen overlapping ideas is how I like subclasses, so I had to give this a shot. My intuition could be wildly off on many of these things.

Comment: Oh my gosh. That was so in depth. I will make sure to apply some of your ideas.  So to clarify some stuff. The bag of resting was essentially meant to be a way for you and your party to more safely take a long rest. I definitely need to work on the wording.     In fact a toooon of it needs wording changed. But the advice has been massively helpful and exactly what I needed.

Comment: I would appreciate if you had any ideas on a different 15th level ability that is more fitting for enhancing the classes abilities.

Comment: So a summary of things I should change. Make bag of safekeeping work specifically with created bags. Clarify the qualities of the connected bags so that you aren't in an inception style bag situation. In a bag that's in a bag that's in a bag that's all in the same spot. Put a limit on porta satchel. And lastly do some general clarifying

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the the Bag of Resting feature doesn't specify that it allows people inside the bag to breathe for more than ten minutes, only that it allows them to stay inside for up to eight hours. Given that the regular bag of holding specifies that it only contains 10 minutes worth of air and doesn't limit how long you can stay inside, this is a serious oversight that actually makes bags of holding _worse_ for resting in than they are by default.

Comment: @GMJoe I can check if there's a question about it, but Tiny Hut's wording presumably means infinite fresh air, or else it wouldn't be "comfortable and dry." Also, Bag of Resting implies that it gives you a huge 10-foot-radius dome of bonus volume, compared to a normal Bag's volume of just 4x4x2 cubic feet. Not a nice place to rest. And... nothing stops you from using it the normal way. I think. But yeah I don't understand the feature.

Comment: For the bag of resting feature it may be helpful to look at the Genie Patron Warlock's Bottled Respite feature (see Tasha's Cauldron of Everything), which seems to have the design intent as this feature

Comment: @Hollow I don't have any really good ideas, but I'd be lazy and just give each (normal) infused Bag a 10x10x5 ft base volume if you want the "rest/craft in comfort" feeling, or give 2 more infusion slots for (normal) Bags only. Also, I only realize now that an Artificer can only have 1 copy of each infusion, so Bag of Safekeeping should probably say that you can infuse as many (normal) Bags as you like.

Comment: @Phoenices Ah! You're right - I was thinking of earlier editions' version of the tiny hut spell, which was much less accommodating. Thanks for the correction.