# Updated Bagweaver Subclass

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, artificer, archetype

I posted here not too long ago asking to get a subclass reviewed ([Bagweaver Artificer Subclass](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/210691/bagweaver-artificer-subclass)). I have since made edits based on you guys' suggestions as well as some from other people. Here is the updated version, the packmaster. Let me know if any changes need to be made.

Bag of Resting is meant to be similar to the genie warlock, but allows long rests inside. To balance it, I made it require a ritual to go inside instead of an action. This one had many errors that made it hard to understand, so hopefully, the new wording has helped.

### Packmaster

The bag of holding has stood out to you as an extraordinary marvel of ingenuity. You seek to master the art of using these miraculous bags' extradimensional properties. No matter what the task at hand, you will always be prepared, and your party can count on you to have just the thing they need.

#### Packmaster Spells

Starting at 3rd level, you always have certain spells prepared after you reach particular levels in this class, as shown in the Packmaster Spells table. These spells count as artificer spells for you, but they don’t count against the number of artificer spells you prepare.

| Artificer Level | Packmaster Spells |
| --- | --- |
| 3rd | Unseen Servant, Tenser's Floating Disk |
| 5th | Misty Step, Cloud of Daggers |
| 9th | Conjure Barrage, Clairvoyance |
| 13th | Dimension Door, Banishment |
| 17th | Steel Wind Strike, Swift Quiver |

#### Bag of Resting

You have studied the inner workings of a bag of holding you've created and have managed to create a space within to call your own. At level 3 you and up to 5 allies can take refuge within a bag of holding. Entering the bag requires a special ritual which takes one minute. Exiting only requires an action.
While within the bag, you and your allies can take long or short rest. During a long rest within the bag, a Packmaster may spend 4 of their long rest hours crafting.
This space is separate from the areas where you keep any items. This is a 20-foot radius cylinder that is 20 feet high. The area within this space is always a comfortable temperature. This area starts with a workstation and basic furnishings. While within this space you can summon any item from within your bag of holding to your hand as an action.

#### Bag of Safekeeping

Also at level 3, your refuge within a bag of holding has allowed you to ensure the safety of your items. When a bag of holding you created is torn, any objects within are kept within the confines of the refuge, and any creatures are safely placed within 10 feet of the torn bag. The next time you create a bag of holding, you regain access to the items within. Moreover, you gain the knowledge to nest one of your created bags within another without complications.

#### Bag of Connecting

Your mastery over bags of holding allows you to attune to the bags. You can attune to any bag of holding you create. At level 5 you also gain 2 additional attunement slots. These slots can only be used for bags of holding you create. You can also create more than one bag of holding using your infusion slots. While attuned to a bag of holding you gain the following benefits.
While within 80 feet of each other, bags of holding attuned to you form a connected network of space. The space within the bags is a 10x10x10-foot cube that can hold 500 pounds. Any connected bags add their space to form a larger space capable of holding more. ex.) 2 connected bags will allow you to hold up to 1000 pounds that fit within a 20x20x20 foot cubic space.
As a bonus action, you can leap between 2 connected bags of holding. This can be used a number of times equal to twice your Proficiency Bonus, and you regain any expended uses when you take a long rest.

#### Bag of Blinking

Also, at 5th level, your bags of holding gain the ability to teleport. As a bonus action, you can choose one bag of holding connected to the network and move it to an unoccupied space within 60 feet that you can see. You can use this ability a number of times equal to your Proficiency Bonus, and you regain any expended uses when you take a long rest.

#### Bag of Fast Hands

At 9th level, your mastery of the extradimensional space allows you to quickly reach into it without a bag. As an action, you can move an object you are touching into or out of your storage network without a bag. You can do this a number of times equal to your intelligence modifier, and you regain any expended uses when you take a long rest. In order to reach into this space, you must be within 80 feet of another bag. The object can also only be up to 64 cubic feet or 500 lbs.

#### Bag of Aid

Also, at 9th level, you are better able to aid allies that hold your bags. When you or an ally is holding a bag you created on their person, they gain the following benefits:

- You can draw ammunition or weapons from the bag as part of an action to attack with them.
- Any attacks can be used as if they were from a different connected bag's space. This does not provide disadvantage to ranged weapons if shot from a bag adjacent to a target.

#### Bag of Dimensions

You have mastered the extradimensional forces within a bag of holding. At level 15 you gain the ability to travel long distances using your bags. You can use this feature to teleport yourself and up to 4 allies to any bag of holding you've created regardless of distance. Everyone will safely appear within 10 feet of the chosen bag.
Alternatively, you can use this feature against an enemy. You can hurl a bag of holding towards a foe, forcing them to make a Dexterity saving throw against your spell save DC. On a success, nothing happens. On a failure you can warp the target to any bag of holding you've created regardless of distance. You can use this feature twice, and you regain any expended uses when you take a long rest.

### Packmaster Infusions

The bag of holding is more than just a bag to you. Your mastery over it has allowed you to create new items utilizing the bag's unique features.

#### Dimensional Whip

This whip is made from the leather of a bag of holding and is able to shape itself at will. When attacking on your turn, you can extend the whip up to an additional 10 feet.
Additional Packmaster Effects:
You are proficient with this whip. A Packmaster can use intelligence when attacking with this whip and gains extra attack at level 5 with this whip. (Does not stack with any other form of extra attack).

#### Astral Sling

This sling is connected to the bag of holding and can draw ammunition from the bag as part of the attack action. You no longer need a free hand to load the sling. Also, when you make a ranged attack with this sling and hit a target, you can cause the ammunition to ricochet toward a second target within 10 feet of the first, and then make a ranged attack against the second target.
Additional Packmaster Effects
As a master of the pocket dimension, a Packmaster can use intelligence when attacking with this sling and gains extra attack at level 5 with this sling. (Does not stack with any other form of extra attack)

Requires 6th level

#### Unfurled Bag of Holding

A bag of holding made this way can be used like a cloak. While wearing this cloak you have advantage on stealth checks as your form is obscured with remnants from the dimension within. While attuned to the cloak, the Packmaster can treat it as a bag of holding. The entrance is the inside of the cloak, and the dimensions for it are based on the Packmaster's size. The height is equal to the Packmaster's height, and the width is equal to the Packmaster’s wingspan (About 6 feet for a medium character).

#### Saddlebag of Holding

This item is a saddle made with a touch of a bag of holding's extradimensional energy. While holding the saddle you can cast the spell Find Steed once per long rest. The steed will appear wherever the saddle is and will disappear if the saddle is removed.

Requires 10th level

#### Dimensional armor

This armor is a +1 version of leather armor. While wearing this armor, you can use your reaction to reduce the damage of an attack that hits you by 1d10. This can be used a number of times equal to the Packmaster's PB per long rest.

#### Warped Caestus

This item is a glove meant to aid in a user's unarmed strikes. These have been made with the power of a bag of holding. While wearing these gloves you gain the following benefits:

- Your unarmed attacks can attack an additional 5 feet away
- When someone is hit by one of your unarmed strikes, they must succeed on a Strength saving throw against your save DC or be moved 5 ft closer to you. (Save DC = 8 + your Proficiency Bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice))
- Anyone hit by your unarmed strikes has their movement speed reduced by 10 feet. (Only once per turn)

Requires 14th level

#### Bag of Spells

This bag of holding cannot connect to your interdimensional network. While holding this bag in your hands you can cast counterspell as a 5th-level spell once ever. If it succeeds it can store the spell inside it, as long as that spell is no higher than 5th level. You can cast that spell at a later time without expending a spell slot, or any materials. The magic will only stay in the bag until a long rest.

#### Greater Saddlebag of Holding

This is an ornate saddle containing the dimensional energy from a bag of holding. While holding the saddle you can cast the spell *Find Greater Steed* without using a spell slot once per long rest. The steed will appear wherever the saddle is and will disappear if the saddle is removed.

[image: Packmaster pg 1]
[image: Packmaster pg 2]
[image: Packmaster pg 3]

Comment: Bag of Connecting: 10x10x10+10x10x10=10x10x20, not 20x20x20 - I assume this was unintentional.

Comment: The image first massively reduces the ability to read the question.

Comment: @Trish  I placed them at the bottom now. Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify: For Bag of Blinking, is it 60 feet relative to the bag, or to you? Like, if the bag is 30 feet away from you, can you teleport it to a space 90 feet away from you, assuming you can see said space?

Comment: I made several edits, mainly replacing "PB" with "your proficiency bonus". Also, some of the infusions (Dimensional Armor) aren't clear on whether they can be used by anyone other than the creator. Finally, I'd suggest (for anywhere I missed) that you change the infusion descriptions to address the creator, as all of the vanilla ones do.

Comment: @Thelittlepeace   for bag of blinking it is relative to the bag assuming you can see it.